# Misunderstanding of Running coupling constants

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization

So, in my particle physics course, the story went like this. Suppose there is an electron alone in the universe and it has a charge $q$ which we'll call bare charge. Now, if we want to interact with it at high energy there will be a high probability of creation and annihilation of pairs during the interaction. In other words, there will be a lot of feynman diagrams with loops of $e^-$ and $e^+$.

The pictoric explanation is that this pairs screen the bare charge as a dielectric medium so the charge we see in the interaction is a screened one.

This sounds as a pedagogic aproach but it actually makes sense. However, the coupling constant vs. Energy plot is the other way around. The screening seems to happen at low energies. The explanation is that low energies means long distancies and that one starts to see the actual electron at short distances (or high energies).

apparently, screening happens at low energies. How is this reconciled with the vacuum polarization explanation? How can pairs can be created at low energies?

P.S.: If the whole pair creation explanation is plain wrong, could you explain why there is an effective charge at different scales of energy?